# How to retrieve all the administrators of a FB page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Scenario:
My web App needs to know all Admins of a FB page to let's the FB page administrators add other Administrators to their company account.

Almost one of the FB page admins has grant the manage_page permissions to my Application.

How could my App retrieve the FBID of other Page Admins? How can I get the page_access_token?

The API /v2.2/me/accounts?access_token=$_SESSION[extended_tokenU] can get the page_access_token only if the authenticated user is a page admin.

Is there any other API able to get the page_access_token on behalf of the App?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `/{page-id}/roles` using a page access token and you will get a list of all users that have a role on the page

Comment: The problem is retrieving the page access token as app and not as user, that api runs only if  the asking user is a page admin. (The API /v2.2/me/accounts?access_token=$_SESSION[extended_tokenU] can get the page_access_token only if the authenticated user is a page admin)

Comment: Of course you can't get a page access token as an app. The user need to grant the app permission to get page access tokens. After that just store the page access token and do what you want

Comment: Yes, I agree but not solve my problem. 
Let's me to be more clear, My app manage various FB page, the FB admin install my app on his page and later he can manage various tools.

Comment: Yes. Just do what I said. I don't understand why that doesn't work for you